# Displaying feature class in scratch geodatabase created by Web Tool in Web Map it was run from

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-portal, arcgis-online-webmap

At [Sharing ArcGIS Pro Python Script as Web Tool gives Analyze error 00068 Script ... contains broken project data source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445324/sharing-arcgis-pro-python-script-as-web-tool-gives-analyze-error-00068-script) I learned how to fix my paths, use a scratch geodatabase and employ a Result object when sharing a working Python Script Tool as a geoprocessing service.

The result of my current tool/service is a point feature class in a scratch geodatabase that I wish to display on the web map that I run the Web Tool from.

This is the code that runs fine in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2 and which I have no problem Sharing as a Web Tool to our ArcGIS Enterprise 11 portal using the settings below.

```
import arcpy,os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

csvFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
test_data_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

gdb = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
csv_table_name = "{0}_CSV".format(test_data_name)
csv_table = os.path.join(gdb,csv_table_name)
pointFC_name = "{0}_points".format(test_data_name)
pointFC =  os.path.join(gdb,pointFC_name)
srGDA2020 = arcpy.SpatialReference("GDA2020")

t2t = arcpy.conversion.TableToTable(csvFile,arcpy.env.scratchGDB,csv_table_name)
arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(t2t,pointFC,"Longitude","Latitude",None,srGDA2020)
```

Note that on the Configuration tab I use the **Upload** option, and this works fine to enable me to browse to an input CSV file.  I also use the **View output in map image layer** option hoping that would enable the point feature class my tool creates to be rendered in my web map.

[image]

[image]

When I locate my Web Tool in the Contents of my Portal and choose Open in Map Viewer Classic, it gives me to GUI that I expect:

[image]

However, when I click RUN ANALYSIS the analysis appears to run but instead of seeing its result added to the web map I get a message:

> Error
>
> The layer, Analysis Result Layer, cannot be added to the map.

At [suggestion of @user2856](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445770/displaying-feature-class-in-scratch-geodatabase-created-by-web-tool-in-web-map-i?noredirect=1#comment727556_445770) I used ArcGIS Server Manager to look at the Logs and found more information about the error:

> Can not open file
> E:\arcgis\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisjobs\testtool_gpserver\j529678a532724ddab9f9469b5a754bfc\Results.msd.
> The system cannot find the file specified. Probable cause: The file is
> inaccessible to Server.

[image]

Unfortunately, that message does not yet mean much to me, but I'll see what I can find out about it from those who administer ArcGIS Enterprise here.

How do I get a feature class that my web tool creates in a scratch geodatabase to be displayed in the web map that I run it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past this without needing to directly address the error seen in the ArcGIS Server Manager by:

1. Modifying my code to include `arcpy.SetParameter()` at its end

---

```
import arcpy,os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

csvFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
test_data_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

gdb = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
csv_table_name = "{0}_CSV".format(test_data_name)
csv_table = os.path.join(gdb,csv_table_name)
pointFC_name = "{0}_points".format(test_data_name)
pointFC =  os.path.join(gdb,pointFC_name)
srGDA2020 = arcpy.SpatialReference("GDA2020")


t2t = arcpy.conversion.TableToTable(csvFile,arcpy.env.scratchGDB,csv_table_name)
result = arcpy.management.XYTableToPoint(t2t,pointFC,"Longitude","Latitude",None,srGDA2020)
arcpy.SetParameter(2,result)
```

---

2. Modifying the Python Script Tool properties to include the parameter I set in my script as FeatureClass, Derived and Output.

[image]

3. Sharing as Web Tool again
4. Testing it in Map Viewer Classic

[image]

[image]